# marginal density valid probability density function

Tags: probability-distributions

fX,Y (x, y) = 24xy, 0 < x < 1, 0 < y < 1, 0 < x + y < 1

(a) Is fX,Y (x, y) a valid probability density function?

using the integral 1→0

12x(1 − x)^2dx

→

12x^3  − 24x^2 + 12xdx =

3-8+6 =1 correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be a valid p.d.f., the function f(x, y) must satisfy 
two conditions: (i) f(x, y) ≥ 0, ∀x, y and

f(x, y)dydx = 1.Clearly f(x, y) is non-negative as it is zero outside of the range
indicated above, and positive inside. In order to check the second
condition we need to integrate the p.d.f. over the shaded region:
that is, the region where y < 1.x for any x that lies between 0 and1. so that's correct